# Excel-Export in SSIS

Tags: excel, ssis, formatting

I am trying to export some data to Excel via `SQL-Server SSIS`.
Everything works so far, but the data in Excel are not recognized as a date or decimal number, so that the user of the sheet first has to laboriously reformat.

Is there a way to export the data directly so that the correct format is recognized?

I select the data via `OLE-DB-Source` from a SQL-Server 2014 and than I do a data conversion to map the fields to the data formats of SSIS:

```
VARCHAR to DT_WSTR,
DECIMAL to DT_R8,
DATE to DT_DATE
```

Finally I use the excel-Export task to create a xlsx-File dynamically.
That works but I want that the data are in the format that the user of the Excel can directly filter and summarizing the data. That doesn't work.